# AWK complains about number of fields when extracting variables

Tags: awk

I have a script to parse a TeamCity directory map file. The script works, but I want to know why refactoring it into using variables breaks it with a seemingly unrelated error message and how I can still have it work using variables.

```
MAP=/opt/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/directory.map                                                                                                                                  
sed -n -e '1,3d;1,/#/{/#/!p}' $MAP | \                                                                                                                                           
awk '   {                                                                                                                                                                        
            n=split($0, array, "->");                                                                                                                                            
            printf(substr(array[1], 6) substr(array[2],2,16) "\n");                                                                                                              
        }                                                                                                                                                                        
'
```

This prints

```
nicecorp::Master 652293808ace4eb5
nicecorp::Reset Database 652293808ace4eb5
nicecorp::test-single-steps 652293808ace4eb5
nicecorp::Develop 652293808ace4eb5
nicecorp::Pull Requests 652293808ace4eb5
```

Which is pretty much what I want.

**The refactoring that breaks**

But then I was trying to extract the sub strings into variables, and the script broke. I changed the last `printf` statement into this

```
proj=substr(array[1], 6); 
tcdir=substr(array[2],2,16);
printf($proj"  " $tcdir);
```

That just prints this error, although I thought it was more or less the same?

```
awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767
        FILENAME="-" FNR=1 NR=1
```

This error seems a bit weird, given that my total input is about 500 bytes, 60 times less than the limit they complain about with regards to fields.

**AWK version**: `mawk` (1994)

**Data format** (`$ head -10 directory.map`):

```
#Don't edit this file!
#Nov 5, 2019 1:49:26 PM UTC
--version=2
bt30=nicecorp::Master -> 652293808ace4eb5 |?| Oct 29, 2019 4:14:27 PM UTC |:| default
bt32=nicecorp::Reset Database -> 652293808ace4eb5 |?| Oct 30, 2019 1:01:48 PM UTC |:| default
bt33=nicecorp::test-single-steps -> b96874cc9acaf874 |?| Nov 4, 2019 4:20:13 PM UTC |:| default
bt33=nicecorp::test-single-steps -> 652293808ace4eb5 |?| Nov 5, 2019 9:00:37 AM UTC |:| default
bt28=nicecorp::Develop -> 652293808ace4eb5 |?| Nov 5, 2019 1:07:53 PM UTC |:| default
bt29=nicecorp::Pull Requests -> 652293808ace4eb5 |?| Nov 5, 2019 1:18:08 PM UTC |:| default
#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the problem is that the print statement in the refactor is using shell notation for variable ($proj instead of proj, $tcdir instead of tcdir).

When those values are numeric (e.g., tcdir=`652293808ace4eb5` for the  first line), awk (mawk in this case) will try to print 652293808-th column. Current version of gawk will not fail here - they will realize there are only few columns, and will show empty string for those field (or the full line for $0, if the value is non numeric)

Older version may attempt to extend the field list array to match the requested number, resulting in `limit exceeded` message.

Also note two minor issues - refactored code uses proj as format - it will get confused if '%' is included. Also, missing newlines. Did you really mean printf and not print ?

Fix:

```
proj=substr(array[1], 6); 
tcdir=substr(array[2],2,16);
# Should consider print, instead of printf
printf(proj "  " tcdir "\n");
# print proj, tcdir
```

Comment: Hi, @dash-o. I found the fix just minutes before you posted your answer, but you have the full details, so I'll give you the answer. I found the issues with the printf as well, and the whole script as it should be is here: https://gist.github.com/fatso83/cee5fb7bf3d9ee59f3caaad6d3ea777d

Answer (score 0):

The problem was syntax. I was using the shell style `$tcdir` to insert the value of the variable instead of simply `tcdir`. By (some unknown to me) means the `tcdir` portion of `$tcdir` is resolved to some numeric field value, meaning I am trying to print the value of a field, not the variable `tcdir`.

Answer (score 0):

@dash-o : just as a point of reference, I just successfully split 428 million fields in `gawk 5.2.2` in `24 secs` (probably even higher but didnt' test its limits),

and some **`1.036 billion fields`** in `mawk2` in `32.8 secs`

```
 ( time ( pvE0 < "$m3r" | 

  gawk -be 'BEGIN { RS = "^$"; FS = OFS = "" } END { print NF }' )

  in0:  408MiB 0:00:00 [2.34GiB/s] [2.34GiB/s] [========>] 100%            
 out9:  0.00 B 0:00:22 [0.00 B/s] [0.00 B/s] [<=> ]
 out9:  10.0 B 0:00:23 [ 432miB/s] [ 432miB/s] [<=> ]


  1 428814321


  ( pvE 0.1 in0 < "$m3r" | gawk -be ; )  

  17.87s user 5.48s system 97% cpu 24.017 total
```

---

```
  time ( pvE0 < "$m3s" | 

  mawk2 'BEGIN { RS = "^$"; FS = OFS = "" } END { print NF }' ) 
                                                                  
  in0:  988MiB 0:00:00 [2.35GiB/s] [2.35GiB/s] [========>] 100%            
 out9:  0.00 B 0:00:31 [ 0.00 B/s] [ 0.00 B/s] [<=>]
 out9:  11.0 B 0:00:32 [ 346miB/s] [ 346miB/s] [<=> ]

 1  1036334374

 ( pvE 0.1 in0 < "$m3s" | mawk2 ; ) 

  10.13s user 15.44s system 77% cpu 32.842 total
```